# stop htaccess from rewriting reformatted urls from php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a database that concatenates a pre-formatted html paragraph of data. Part of that paragraph can be a url, which is wrapped properly in  tags. My website (Joomla v3 CMS, rewrite on, with native php inside the articles) searches the database and shows the pre-formatted paragraph just fine. But instead of the url link from the paragraph being just http://doi.org/etc it looks like example.com/%20http://doi.org/etc
Is there either a php command for the paragraph to ignore the htaccess redirect, or possibly a htaccess RewriteRule I can place at the top of the htaccess file that says if the URL is not from example.com, don't apply any redirects?
Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

It was the %20 that finally got me to figure it out. The problem went all the way back to the database. The url inside the href tag had a space between the quotation mark and the http.